# Comparing properties of networks of different sizes

Tags: graph-theory, social-network

I want to compare some network properties such as density, average path and modularity among groups of sizes ranging from 100 to 4000.

How can I correctly compare these networks? Considering the densities, for example, it seems to me that I need to apply an adjustment factor to compensate the fact that the number of potential connections grows exponentially. It is much harder for the larger network to materialize, let’s say, 50% of its almost 8 million potential connections than it is for the 100-node network to materialize 2,5k connections.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks in advance.